# get url redirect for a cms page

Tags: magento-enterprise, cms, url-rewrite, enterprise-1.14

I'm currently implementing a multilanguage store in magento enterprise using german and french store views. one of the requirements is that paths are translated. as an example, I'm trying to link the cms page for the ToS in the layout's footer:

**defined cms pages:**

- "AGB" (german, url key: 'page-info-tos', store view 'de')
- "CGV" (french, url key: 'page-info-tos', store view 'fr')

**defined redirects:**

- "agb" → "page-info-tos"; store view 'de'; no redirect
- "cgv" → "page-info-tos"; store view 'fr'; no redirect
- "cgv" → "agb"; store view 'de'; 301-redirect
- "agb" → "cgv"; store view 'fr'; 301-redirect

**code in footer.phtml:**

`<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('page-info-tos');"><?php echo $this->__('ToS'); ?></a>`

**resulting html:**

`<a href="/de/page-info-tos">AGB</a>` resp `<a href="/fr/page-info-tos">CGV</a>`

**wanted html:**

`<a href="/de/agb">AGB</a>` resp `<a href="/fr/cgv">CGV</a>`

---

how can I lookup the correct request path for the given cms page url key?

Answer (score 1):

by querying the Enterprise_UrlRewrite Url_Rewrite model, it's possible to get the translated url.

**prerequisite: defined redirects:**

- "agb" → "page-info-tos"; store view 'de'; no redirect
- "cgv" → "page-info-tos"; store view 'fr'; no redirect
- "page-info-tos" → "agb"; store view 'de'; 301-redirect (only used for lookup)
- "page-info-tos" → "cgv"; store view 'fr'; 301-redirect (only used for lookup)

**php code to get the translated url in footer.phtml:**

```
function getTranslatedPath($key)
{
    $urw = Mage::getModel('enterprise_urlrewrite/url_rewrite');
    /* @var $urw Enterprise_UrlRewrite_Model_Url_Rewrite */

    if ($urw->loadByRequestPath(['request' => $key])->getId())
        return $urw->getTargetPath();
    else
        return $key; // no rewrite found or matched
}

?>
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(getTranslatedPath('page-info-tos')); ?>">...</a>
```

although it works - href is `http://example.com/de/agb/` - this feels like an awkward solution. shouldn't rather `$this->getUrl('page-info-tos', ['_use_redirect' => true])` do this lookup for me?

Comment: No, `$this->getUrl('page-info-tos')` does NOT get the URL for the CMS page with code 'page-info-tos' but for a (nonexistant) module `page-info-tos` (actually the route `page-info-tos/index/index`).

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you have set top cms page with same identifier a
Step1:goto admin>Catalog>Url Rewrite manager> a
 and create custom redirection:

```
page-info-tos->agb and store de

page-info-tos->cgv and store fr
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but this is an enterprise question. the enterprise edition does not have "URL Rewrites" but rather "URL Redirects", which are implemented differently. the redirects there do not have identifiers. besides, the redirects are already working, the question is about getting the right cms page url in the footer links without having to have n footers for n languages.

Comment: also......enterprice have a rewrite manger then do this using

Comment: well, the goal is to have the translated url in the html, and not redirect _after_ loading the non-translated url...

Answer (score 0):

I think [this extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/CmsRewrites) is what you need.
After installing it you will see a new menu item and if you click on it you will see an UI where you have to enter the URL key for the pages in each language and it will create the url rewrites for you.

but it will solve only the redirect problem.
You still have to create different footers for different languages.

Comment: thanks, but this is an enterprise question, the extension is not compatible with EE. besides, the redirects are already working _if_ the request is made with the correct translated url. the question is about getting the right cms page url in the footer links without having to have n footers for n languages.